# How to return an floating point array

Tags: c, printf

I need a function that creates an array with some floating points.

```
double * my_function( )
{
    static double arr[10] = {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29};

    return arr;
}


int main ()
{
    double *first_pos;
    int i;

    first_pos = my_function();
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d", *(first_pos + i));
    }

return 0;
}
```

This prints some "random" numbers.

I'm a confused about pointers/arrays!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pointer/array usage is fine.

```
printf("%f", *(p + i));
```

Print doubles with the `%f` specifier. `%d` is for ints.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is  %lf  (long float) for doubles, and %f for normal floats

like this

```
  first_pos = my_function();
  for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    printf( "%lf\n", *(first_pos + i));
  }
```

the output it gives me is

```
20.000000
21.000000
22.000000
23.000000
24.000000
25.000000
26.000000
27.000000
28.000000
29.000000
```

Comment: This is an old question, however all (useful) contributions are welcome!